# How to force DOM element in VueJS to be rendered within the App.vue component

Tags: vue.js, dom, vuejs2, clippy.js

I am currently playing with Clippy.js, a js implementation of the old school Microsoft Agent.
The problem occurs as I want to render the agent inside the App.vue component in my VueJS project. Though, i can't seem to figure out how to bind the agent to App.vue component, or any of its children.

The agent is loaded as follows:

```
<script>
import 'clippyjs';
methods: {
clippy() {
      clippy.load('Clippy', (agent) => {
        agent.show();
        agent.animate();
      });
    }
}
</script>
```

The code is from a method in my Header.app component, which is a child component of App.vue

LINK TO DIRECTORY : https://github.com/pi0/clippyjs

Comment: Not sure what you mean for `I want to render the agent inside the App.vue component in my VueJS project.` the Clippy js control the render for its agent, Vue can't control `clippy.js` where to put its agents. From the demo in the official site, `clippy.js` always put its agents as direct children of `body`.

Comment: @Sphinx is there a work around where you can bind the dom element to a specific div or something, possibly with css code ? thx for helpful answers

Answer (score 0):

Below is **one simple demo** to integrate `clippy`.

The key point is fetch the agent instance inside the callback of `clippy.load`, then execute the actions you need by invoke the related APIs agent instance provides.

`Clippy.js` will add extra Dom elements under `<body>`, so we'd better to clear them up if necessary (like: component destroyed).

Anyway, the implementation of `Clippy.js` is based on real Dom through `JQuery`, Vue is based on Virtual Node. It makes the things a little complicate if uses `Clippy.js` in Vue project.

```js
Vue.component('v-clippy',{
    template:`
        <div>
            <button v-show="!this.agent" @click="loadClippy()">Load Clippy</button>
            <button v-show="this.agent" @click="show()">Show</button>
            <button v-show="this.agent" @click="hide()">Hide</button>
            <button v-show="this.agent" @click="play()">Play</button>
            <button v-show="this.agent" @click="animate()">Animate</button>
            <button v-show="this.agent" @click="destroy()">Destroy</button>
        </div>
    `,
    props: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Links'
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {
        agent: null
      }
    },
    mounted: function () {
      this.loadClippy()
    },
    methods: {
      loadClippy: function () {
        clippy.load(this.name, (agent) => {
          this.agent = agent
        })
      },
      show: function () {
        this.agent && this.agent.show()
      },
      hide: function () {
        this.agent && this.agent.hide()
      },
      play: function () {
        this.agent && this.agent.play('Searching')
      },
      animate: function () {
        this.agent.animate()
      },
      destroy: function () {
        this.agent._el.remove() // this.agent._el is the JQuery object binds to the Dom of Agent
        this.agent = null
      }
    }
})

new Vue ({
  el:'#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/pi0/clippyjs/master/assets/clippy.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.2.1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/clippyjs@latest"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div>
        <h3>Test Clippy</h3>
        <div>
            <v-clippy></v-clippy>
            <v-clippy name="Merlin"></v-clippy>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx for useful answer, i kind of figured out a work around to get the wanted outcome with adding some css values to the DOM element rendered with jquery.